# What items can be transferred as non-muted?

Tags: dota-2

I noticed that all consumable items can be traded during a game and remain non-muted.  But, I was surprised to find that ring of regeneration was also non-muted when I traded it.

What items can be transferred between heroes and not be muted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All consumables can be shared and used by teammates:

- Tangos
- Healing Salve
- Clarity
- Bottle
- Observer Ward
- Sentry Ward
- Animal Courier
- Flying Courier
- Dust
- Smoke
- TP Scroll
- Cheese

Additionally, basic regeneration items can be shared:

- Ring of Regen
- Sage's Mask
- Ring of Health
- Void Stone
- Perseverance

Gem can also be shared. Bottle and Divine Rapier have some interesting rules about sharing that don't come up much: you can't pass off bottled runes, but you can pass a Bottle and your teammate can fill it with a rune, then use it. Divine Rapiers can only be shared if an ally dies and a teammate picks it up, in which case it can be shared only with the original owner.

Answer (score 5):

Besides, like you said, all consumables (wards, courier, tangos, clarities...) can be traded.

The few exceptions to the rule are **ring of regeneration**, **ring of health**, **sage's mask**, **void stone**, and **perseverance**. the logic, *I've inferred*, being:

1. you only get **regen, and no other stat**. unlike, say, hood of defiance, which gives health regen, but also magic resistance. the exception here being perseverance, which while it gives +10 damage, that damage is muted, the regen isn't.
2. it **can't be upgraded into other items** by the person receiving it, and is sort of muted in that sense. otherwise you'd see some strategy of giving a pooling a carry rings of regen at the start of the game.

also, bottles that have a rune in them can't be shared. otherwise, with 0 to 3 charges, they can be given to and used by allies (or enemies!).

Comment: Good to know they can't be used to upgrade